# Why cannot I delete unique_ptr<char[]> with reset()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, unique-ptr

When I have an unique pointer to a single object, I can delete it with `reset()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char> variable(new char);
variable.reset();
```

However, this does not work for an `std::unique_ptr` containing an array. Why? What is the proper way to delete such pointer?

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.1. and the relevant standard is C++11.

### My observations

When I have an unique pointer containing an array, this fails to compile:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> variable(new char[10]);
variable.reset();
```

Error message is `no matching function to call for 'reset'`.

This also fails:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> variable(new char[10]);
variable.reset(nullptr);
```

Error messages are `cannot initialize a variable of type 'pointer' (aka 'char *') with an lvalue of type '<bound member function type>'` and `assigning to '<bound member function type>' from incompatible type '_Null_ptr_type' (aka 'nullptr_t')`.

This compiles:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> variable(new char[10]);
variable = nullptr;
```

### Relevant code from <memory>

```
template<class _Uty>
using _Enable_ctor_reset = enable_if_t<
    is_same<_Uty, pointer>::value
    || (is_same<pointer, element_type *>::value
    && is_pointer<_Uty>::value
    && is_convertible<
        remove_pointer_t<_Uty>(*)[],
        element_type(*)[]
    >::value)>;

_Myt& operator=(_Null_ptr_type) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // assign a null pointer
    reset(pointer());
    return (*this);
    }

_NOINLINE void reset(_Null_ptr_type _Ptr) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // establish new null pointer
    pointer _Old = this->_Myptr;
    this->_Myptr = _Ptr;
    if (_Old != pointer())
        this->get_deleter()(_Old);
    }

template<class _Uty,
    class = _Enable_ctor_reset<_Uty> >
void reset(_Uty _Ptr) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // establish new pointer
    pointer _Old = get();
    this->_Myptr() = _Ptr;
    if (_Old != pointer())
        this->get_deleter()(_Old);
    }
```

Comment: As a guess the compiler is not compliant

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c14fa9b7a88e057 runs fine on gcc as I expected, so your compiler must've some kind of issue with it. Maybe try contacting the C++ Builder company?

Comment: Working fine with gcc (c++11) compiler

Comment: `_Enable_ctor_reset` looks like some kind of `std::enable_if`: I am curious to see the code behind, but I guess it disables `reset` for arrays

Comment: @wasthishelpful I added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in the standard library, because the same code compiles with other compilers, as pointed out by [deW1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3065406/dew1) and [sanjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057286/sanjay) in comments.

C++11 standard, section 20.7.1.3 (*"unique_ptr for array objects with a runtime length"*) lists `reset()` with the following signature:

> void reset(pointer p = pointer()) noexcept;

The first example fails to compile, because the default argument is missing from the standard library implementation. The second example essentially calls `reset(pointer())`, which fails to compile. Possibly this compile error is the reason why the default argument has not been added.

I have made a bug report to Embarcadero:

[RSP-16165 Compile error when calling reset() on unique_ptr containing array object](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16165)